# Access localhost on windows 7 VMWare Fusion

Tags: vmware

I am developing a .Net API service in Windows 7 box and try to debug API from my Mac OS, however, I am not able to hit the API through the port (3345). I used ipconfig to find out my windows7 IP address, and then try to access it through (address:port), and it never connects.

Anything I need to do on VMFusion to allow me hit the .Net API.